# Pandas: get rid off rows where there is no value

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
time    Time1_high  Price1_high Time2_high  Price2_high Time1_low   Price1_low  Time2_low   Price2_low                      

5   2019-04-22 00:02:00                             
6   2019-04-22 00:02:15                             
7   2019-04-22 00:02:30                         2019-04-22 00:02:30 0.00185691
8   2019-04-22 00:02:45                             
9   2019-04-22 00:03:00                             
10  2019-04-22 00:03:15                             
11  2019-04-22 00:03:30                             
12  2019-04-22 00:03:45                             
13  2019-04-22 00:04:00                 2019-04-22 00:04:15 0.00185499      
14  2019-04-22 00:04:15                             
15  2019-04-22 00:04:30                             
16  2019-04-22 00:04:45                             
17  2019-04-22 00:05:00                             
18  2019-04-22 00:05:15                             
19  2019-04-22 00:05:30                             
20  2019-04-22 00:05:45                             
21  2019-04-22 00:06:00                             
22  2019-04-22 00:06:15         2019-04-22 00:06:15 0.00185391              
23  2019-04-22 00:06:30                             
24  2019-04-22 00:06:45                             
25  2019-04-22 00:07:00                             
26  2019-04-22 00:07:15                             
27  2019-04-22 00:07:30                             
28  2019-04-22 00:07:45 2019-04-22 00:08:00 0.00185587                      
29  2019-04-22 00:08:00
```

What I need in fact is really to get rid off the columns where there is no data for all the columns below `[Time1_high,  Price1_high, Time2_high,  Price2_high, Time1_low,   Price1_low,  Time2_low,   Price2_low ]`

So that I really just have a summary of the columns where thare are value. It should looks like this:

```
    time    Time1_high  Price1_high Time2_high  Price2_high Time1_low   Price1_low  Time2_low   Price2_low                      



    7   2019-04-22 00:02:30                         2019-04-22 00:02:30 0.00185691
    13  2019-04-22 00:04:00                 2019-04-22 00:04:15 0.00185499      
    22  2019-04-22 00:06:15         2019-04-22 00:06:15 0.00185391              
    28  2019-04-22 00:07:45 2019-04-22 00:08:00 0.00185587
```

Comment: Does 'no value' mean empty string '' or NaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try using the `dropna` method?

`df.dropna(how='all')` , the `'all'`  will drop if all the values are `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

If missing values are empty strings filter all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), test for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for return at least one `True` per row:

```
df1 = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].ne('').any(axis=1)]
```

Or if missing values are `NaN`s use [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
df1 = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].notna().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: The first line of code gave me the desired result! thanks